# Elements selected from two different selectors in CSS. The first is working, but the second isn't

Tags: css

I want to make a pricing table with three columns. Such as:

```
* Basic Package *        * BEST VALUE *         * Legendary 7 *
   Awesomeness              Awesome+               Awesome++
    24/7 Chat             Chat + Email           24/7 1-(800) #
      etc.                    etc.                   etc.
```

Obviously, the "best-value" column would be highlighted or focus by some color or special decoration. But, I want my stylesheet to adapt for a different number of columns.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="colx3 pricingPlan">
  <div class="plan">Basic</div>
  <div class="spotlight">Basic</div>
  <div class="plan">Basic</div>
</div>
```

This CSS **does not work**:

```
.pricingPlan>div {
  background:#999;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.colx3>.plan, .colx3>.spotlight {
  width:33%;
}
```

This CSS *does work*:

```
.pricingPlan>div {
  background:#999;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:33%;
}

.colx3>.plan, .colx3>.spotlight {
  /// EMPTY /////////
}
```

I don't want to combine the two selectors under one set of properties, but I think it should work the way I have it. How can I define the style of an element in two different ways? More importantly, how do I get the columns to resize dependent upon the number of total columns (defined in the class name colx3).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your css there, it runs perfectly fine - http://jsfiddle.net/jut2shxw/

There must be something else in your code overwriting the styles. Your best bet is to look with the chrome inspector, and see what else is being applied to your divs.

Comment: thats true your code working fine but if its not working give the !important property . It will work .colx3>.plan, .colx3>.spotlight {
  width:32.3% !important;
} and  .pricingPlan>div {
  background:#999 !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
  margin:0 auto !important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is make columns of `<div>`s float in one row. So the latter CSS does work because in it the `<div>`s are defined with the property `display:inline-block;` which aligns them beside each other with a width of 33%. If you use the former CSS (the one you mentioned not working) and add `float: left;` after the defined width (`width:33%;`) in the selector `.colx3>.plan, .colx3>.spotlight`it will work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/anujbhai/wey5j61f/) is a fiddle

In order to resize columns depending upon the number of columns in a row, you can either use a JavaScript (not provided here) or a mere CSS approach, via setting the parent element with `display: table;` and the child columns with `display: table-cell;` might also work.

Also the `.clearfix` is defined so that the columns do not fall apart in case more `<div>`s are added to the document (just a fail-safe technique).